# Will the VMs on the ESXi cluster be running after disconnection from the network?

Tags: vmware-esxi

What will happen if I disconnect the ESXi cluster configured with HA from the switch(I need to change the power source on the main switch) and there is no management port redundancy? I'm going to disable the host monitoring and VM monitoring within HA settings, and connect to the switch after it boots up.

Will the virtual machines be running if I disconnect the hosts from the network so they will not see any other ESXi host? I hope everything will work fine and the hosts will join the cluster after they connect to the network again, but I would like to be sure ..

Comment: I am aware of this, and it is meant to be temporary.. But thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host's behavior in the situation where it's disconnected from the network is determined by the "Host Isolation Response" setting in the cluster's VMware HA -> Virtual Machine Options section.

If it's set to "Leave powered on" (the default), then even if a VMware HA response kicks in from the other cluster members, they'll be unable to start the VMs; the storage locks that the isolated host has on them will prevent boot on another host.

Comment: In fact, this was the right answer. I rather turned off the vmware ha completely on the whole cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you unplug the network cable from management card, I would assume that the vcenter will think the esxi host can't be joined and will act like it has been powered off and HA feature will start.

So if you disable HA settings for this Host/VMs you should not have any problem.

Comment: Should I disable HA completely or just the Host and VM monitoring feature?

Comment: Those options do exactly what it sounds like they do.